# How to detect vertical and horizontal lines from scanned document with Python and OpenCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, opencv, handwriting-recognition

I'm having problem when binary the image then use HoughLineP function to get vertical and horizontal lines, but look like my threshold parameter or not filter image before binary it cause some dots on the line, then the HoughLineP can not detect exactly the lines. Is there anyway to fix this?

My code (references https://github.com/fazlurnu/Text-Extraction-Table-Image):

`main.py`

```
from preprocessing import get_grayscale, get_binary, invert_area, draw_text, detect, image_resize
from ROI_selection import detect_lines, get_ROI
import cv2 as cv

filename = 'images/tmp2.png'
    
src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(filename))
# src = image_resize(src, height=1000)
    
gray_scale = get_grayscale(src)
bw = get_binary(gray_scale, threshold1=210, threshold2=255)
cv.imshow("bw", bw)
horizontal, vertical = detect_lines(bw, threshold=127, minLinLength=180, maxLineGap=6, display=True, write = False, grayscale = False)
```

`preprocessing.py`

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

import cv2 as cv
from ROI_selection import detect_lines, get_ROI
import numpy as np

def get_grayscale(image):
    return cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def get_binary(image, threshold1 = 100, threshold2 = 255, threshType = cv.THRESH_BINARY):
    (thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv.threshold(image, threshold1, threshold2, threshType)
    return blackAndWhiteImage

def invert_area(image, x, y, w, h, display=False):
    ones = np.copy(image)
    ones = 1
    
    image[ y:y+h , x:x+w ] = ones*255 - image[ y:y+h , x:x+w ] 
    
    if (display): 
        cv.imshow("inverted", image)
        cv.waitKey(0)
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
    return image
    
def detect(cropped_frame, is_number = False):
    if (is_number):
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_frame,
                                           config ='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789 --psm 10 --oem 2')
    else:
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_frame, config='--psm 10')        
        
    return text

def draw_text(src, x, y, w, h, text):
    cFrame = np.copy(src)
    cv.rectangle(cFrame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv.putText(cFrame, "text: " + text, (50, 50), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,  
               2, (0, 0, 0), 5, cv.LINE_AA)
    
    return cFrame
        
def erode(img, kernel_size = 5):
    kernel = np.ones((kernel_size,kernel_size), np.uint8) 
    img_erosion = cv.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=2)
    return img_erosion

def image_resize(image, width = None, height = None, inter = cv.INTER_AREA):
    # initialize the dimensions of the image to be resized and
    # grab the image size
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    # if both the width and height are None, then return the
    # original image
    if width is None and height is None:
        return image

    # check to see if the width is None
    if width is None:
        # calculate the ratio of the height and construct the
        # dimensions
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)

    # otherwise, the height is None
    else:
        # calculate the ratio of the width and construct the
        # dimensions
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    # resize the image
    resized = cv.resize(image, dim, interpolation = inter)

    # return the resized image
    return resized
```

`ROI_selection.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jun 16 15:48:11 2020

@author: My Laptop
"""

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jun 16 14:19:57 2020

@author: My Laptop
"""

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jun 16 13:48:51 2020

@author: My Laptop
"""

"""
@file hough_lines.py
@brief This program demonstrates line finding with the Hough transform
"""
import sys
import math
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def is_vertical(line):
    return line[0]==line[2]

def is_horizontal(line):
    return line[1]==line[3]
    
def overlapping_filter(lines, sorting_index):
    filtered_lines = []
    
    lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda lines: lines[sorting_index])
    
    for i in range(len(lines)):
            l_curr = lines[i]
            if(i>0):
                l_prev = lines[i-1]
                if ( (l_curr[sorting_index] - l_prev[sorting_index]) > 5):
                    filtered_lines.append(l_curr)
            else:
                filtered_lines.append(l_curr)
                
    return filtered_lines
               
def detect_lines(image, title='default', rho = 1, theta = np.pi/180, threshold = 50, minLinLength = 290, maxLineGap = 6, grayscale = True, display = False, write = False):
    # Check if image is loaded fine
    if grayscale:
        gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
        gray = image
        
    if gray is None:
        print ('Error opening image!')
        return -1
    
    dst = cv.Canny(gray, 50, 150, None, 3)
    
    # Copy edges to the images that will display the results in BGR
    cImage = np.copy(image)
    
    #linesP = cv.HoughLinesP(dst, 1 , np.pi / 180, 50, None, 290, 6)
    linesP = cv.HoughLinesP(dst, rho , theta, threshold, None, minLinLength, maxLineGap)
    
    horizontal_lines = []
    vertical_lines = []
    
    if linesP is not None:
        #for i in range(40, nb_lines):
        for i in range(0, len(linesP)):
            l = linesP[i][0]

            if (is_vertical(l)):
                vertical_lines.append(l)
                
            elif (is_horizontal(l)):
                horizontal_lines.append(l)
        
        horizontal_lines = overlapping_filter(horizontal_lines, 1)
        vertical_lines = overlapping_filter(vertical_lines, 0)
            
    if (display):
        for i, line in enumerate(horizontal_lines):
            cv.line(cImage, (line[0], line[1]), (line[2], line[3]), (0,255,0), 3, cv.LINE_AA)
            
            cv.putText(cImage, str(i) + "h", (line[0] + 5, line[1]), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,  
                       0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv.LINE_AA) 
            
        for i, line in enumerate(vertical_lines):
            cv.line(cImage, (line[0], line[1]), (line[2], line[3]), (0,0,255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)
            cv.putText(cImage, str(i) + "v", (line[0], line[1] + 5), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,  
                       0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1, cv.LINE_AA) 
            
        cv.imshow("Source", cImage)
        #cv.imshow("Canny", cdstP)
        cv.waitKey(0)
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        
    if (write):
        cv.imwrite("../Images/" + title + ".png", cImage);
        
    return (horizontal_lines, vertical_lines)

def get_cropped_image(image, x, y, w, h):
    cropped_image = image[ y:y+h , x:x+w ]
    return cropped_image
    
def get_ROI(image, horizontal, vertical, left_line_index, right_line_index, top_line_index, bottom_line_index, offset=4):
    x1 = vertical[left_line_index][2] + offset
    y1 = horizontal[top_line_index][3] + offset
    x2 = vertical[right_line_index][2] - offset
    y2 = horizontal[bottom_line_index][3] - offset
    
    w = x2 - x1
    h = y2 - y1
    
    cropped_image = get_cropped_image(image, x1, y1, w, h)
    
    return cropped_image, (x1, y1, w, h)
```

**Here is input image:**

[image: Input image]

**Here is some output image:**

Output image: (top) is binary image, (bottom) is binary image with lines from HoughLineP result.

[image: Output image: (top) is binary image, (bottom) is binary image with lines from HoughLineP result]